# What's the meaning of this quotation from Rollo May?

Tags: meaning

Rollo May, in his book *The Courage to Create*, said,

> Commitment is healthiest when it is not without doubt but in spite of doubt.

Would someone please paraphrase this sentence?

Comment: What do you think it means?  What has your research told you so far?  Are there words you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

> Commitment is healthiest when it is not without doubt but in spite of doubt.

Is the above quotation from a book? If so, I assume the author of the sentence goes on in his book to tell his readers what his somewhat cryptic sentence means. If, however, subsequent sentences fail to make his meaning clear to you, then here is my attempt at paraphrasing the author:

> To many people, true *commitment* has no room for doubt. If you are truly committed, say, to a course of action, people tend to think your commitment can be measured by a complete lack of doubt you are doing the right thing. What makes commitment truly healthy, however, is the willingness to forge ahead *in spite of* your doubts. Your doubts, in other words, show how committed you are when you are willing to put them aside and forge ahead anyway.

I am sure someone else could paraphrase the quotation in far fewer words, but I'm hoping my paraphrase clarifies what is truly a cryptic sentence and pregnant with meaning.